# Running a subprocess in a python script using a loop to iterate over files in a directory

Tags: python, loops, unix, subprocess

I'm trying to run a bash subprocess in python script. However, I seem to be getting the error:

"Please provide the filename(s) of one or more FastQ file(s) to launch Trim Galore!

USAGE:  'trim_galore [options] '    or    'trim_galore --help'    for more options"

I wish to iterate over a directory and insert the two files I need into the read1 and read2 variables as a pair into the subprocess (hence the use of indexing) 
I don't understand why I'm getting the above error! Not sure why it thinks I haven't provided filenames.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

```html
import os
import subprocess

indir = "/Users/ainefairbrother/Documents/MSc_Project/TORC_data/unzipped_pretrim"

f = 12
num_of_files = 12
while num_of_files <= f:
    pair_count = 1
    for root, dirs, all_files in os.walk(indir):
        read1 = all_files[pair_count]
        pair_count += 1
        read2 = all_files[pair_count]
        print(read1, read2)
        pair_count += 1
        process = subprocess.run(['trim_galore', '--paired', '--nextera', read1, read2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) #stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)   #shell=True) #stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
        print(process)
    if pair_count > num_of_files:
        break
```

Comment: It's difficult to assist without any idea of what your script outputs. If you print `process.cmd` you should be able to see the full command that was used which might help clarify your issue.
If you're not running the code from `indir` then I'd guess you might need to provide an absolute path to the file arguments.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. Will have a go at that.